# Strange network problem (ssh) after hardware switch - packet loss?

Tags: networking, ssh, tcp

My machine crashed (would not start) and so I pulled my harddrives and memory (which was not stock) and brought to another identical Dell optiplex 755 which I found in the office. Now everything seems to work fine except for sporadic network behavior when connecting through ssh either to or from the new machine. After around a minute or so I get a broken pipe. If I run with strace all I get is "reset by peer".

Now, although I am completely new to debugging tcp issues, with the help of [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20061/ssh-tunnel-to-router-periodically-hangs-tcp-problem) my thinking is that it could have something to do with dropped tcp packets. When I run

```
> netstat -s -p
```

I find that the "segments retransmitted" counter increased with 4 at the point where I got the broken pipe.

Before finding the above post I did the below tests suspecting it had something to do with the changed hardware itself:
 1. ethtool eth0 (shows nothing weird, have full duplex)
 2. ethtool -t eth0 (PASS)
 3. dig (says NOERROR)

Any suggestions on what the problem could be and how/if I might be able to fix it?

Comment: I recall seeing some networking oddness when we started to clone linux systems in our clusters, because udev still had entries for the original system's MAC addresses. Look at /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules and remove any rules from the old computer, and reboot.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately only the new MAC adress was found in  /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by switching to yet a third Dell optiplex 755 motherboard that had a defect graphics card. So, this time I brought HDD, memory and graphics card. I noticed however that I got my original ip-address back. So the problem is most likely to have been caused by changed ip (last set of numbers went from 69 -> 70 and then back to 69)  or by some issue with the network hardware on the second board.